# Adf solution in visual studio 2015 stopped loading

Tags: visual-studio, azure-data-factory

I have an adl-adf pipeline that is in a visual studio 2015 solution. Everything was working until last weekend and some mysterious update happened that rendered my environment useless. The error vs was raising was a cryptic 'vs 2015 stopped working' kind of an error. I dug through the 'adl tools for vs' logs and deduced that it's a versioning problem in gac; uninstalled and reinstalled the data lake tools and at least my vs starts up now.

However, along the process I must have done something to my adf components since the projects in the solution are now failing to load with an error like this.

[image: while loading the solution this appears when the data factory projects fail to load with the invalid pointer error]

Have any of you come across with this? I appreciate your help!

### Here is some relevant version info

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038

Installed Version: Community

.....

Azure Data Lake Node   1.0
This package contains the Data Lake integration nodes for Server Explorer.

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.0.8000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Common Azure Tools   1.7
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

DataFactoryProject   1.0
Microsoft Data Factory Package

....

Microsoft Azure Data Factory Node Node   1.0
Azure Data Factory extension for Visual Studio Server Explorer.

....

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.9.40323.3

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.8
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.8.40211.2

....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, anyone else is having the same problem, I renamed Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.dll mentioned in msdn forum below and it seemed to have done the job as a workaround.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3bd88bd1-7125-4e76-9d3e-79a80d8b071d/visual-studio-2015-crashes-with-azure-data-lake-extension?forum=AzureDataLake